# how to check if a method has been called in a lifecycle hook (JEST + VUE)?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

Okey, I have some test method and lifecycle hook

```
 testMethod(){
      console.log('test')
    }

  beforeMount() {
    this.testMethod()
  },
```

**test**

```
import {createLocalVue, shallowMount} from "@vue/test-utils"
import TestComponents from '../../assets/components/TestComponents'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

describe('test component TestComponents', () => {
    let wrapper = shallowMount(TestComponents,
        {
            localVue
        })
    test('beforeMount hook', async () => {
        let testMethodSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'testMethod')
        expect(testMethodSpy).toBeCalled()
    })
})
```

Why is the method called(in command line "console.log test") but the validation returns an error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SvLd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8b63.png)

Comment: It's because you're mocking method after the component is mounted

Comment: And how to fixed, do you have any idea?